# Android SDK Manager not picking up SDK Path properly

Tags: android

I am trying to update my android SDK Tools and I am having a weird issue with the SDK manager not fetching the current android sdk path.It picks the path as shown below in the snap

[image]

Whereas my current SDK path is **F:\Work\Eclipse & Android\Android\android-sdk**

I have the SDK already installed but its not fetching the correct path.
I am using Eclipse Kepler and my ADT version is 22.3

Is there a way in which this path could be resolved?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what caused the issue but I have it resolved for now.
I had to move my entire Android SDK to another folder and change my SDK path from Eclipse preferences.
The SDK manager is now fetching the correct SDK path.

Answer (score 1):

**For Android Studio:**

1. Press F4 into Project Structure
2. Left > SDKs
3. Press +, add another sdk

**For Eclipse:**

1. Open Eclipse and go to Preferences (Window -> Preferences), select
   the Android tab and Browse to you SDK location.

If this not works try to reinstall Android SDK

Comment: This doesn't help.I am using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

go to **windows**-->**preferences**-->**android** 
then browse `F:\Work\Eclipse & Android\Android\android-sdk`
click on **OK** and you are done

Comment: I had done that.The problem wasn't with the loading of SDK but updating the SDK tools from SDK manager.The manager simply wasn't loading on the correct path.